# Empty error message when deploying sysML v2 API on a VM

Tags: java, playframework, virtual-machine, sysml

I'm trying to deploy the sysML v2 API on a terminal-only linux VM. Documentation: https://github.com/Systems-Modeling/SysML-v2-API-Services

The Setup and building process works just fine. After building I want to connect to the API via the browser of my host (chrome on windows 10).
Instead of connecting to localhost I connect to the IP address of my VM (I replaced it for security reasons).

The API call does get processed (I can see things being compiled on the terminal of the API, while I have a white screen in the browser window), but instead of displaying the swagger UI I got an error message:

> {"error":{"requestId":1,"message":"Host not allowed: ipa.dd.r.ess:9000"}}

I fixed that by adding the IP address to the application.conf file before building.

```
play.filters.hosts { allowed = ["ipa.dd.r.ess"] }
```

When connecting after building the host address related error was resolved, but instead I got a new error:

> {"error":{"requestId":1,"message":""}}

I have tried to interpret that "error message" but didn't find any useful information.

Any help is appreciated.